# Payara Micro installed but error 404 is displayed

Tags: http-status-code-404, war, application-server, payara-micro

I installed Payara Micro (payara-micro-5.201.jar) on my pc, since I have to run a Java application (in a WAR file) as client-server on it.

Some elements to consider about this installation:

- I have no IDEs on my pc, and do not need to install any (I am not coding this application)
- The application I am going to install (.WAR file) will work on port 8333.
- My pc is behind a network firewall (if useful).

From the logs hereby attached, the installation of Payara Micro through command line seems working:

```
C:\WebUpStandalone>java -jar payara-micro-5.201.jar
[2020-03-23T12:01:31.281+0100] [] [[1;93mAVVERTENZA[0m] [] [[1;94mPayaraMicro[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961291281] [levelValue: 900] Payara Micro Runtime directory is located in a temporary file location which can be cleaned by system processes.

[2020-03-23T12:01:31.300+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mPayaraMicro[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961291300] [levelValue: 800] Payara Micro Runtime directory is located at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\payaramicro-rt7345407246578026361tmp

[2020-03-23T12:01:31.313+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.micro.boot.runtime.PayaraMicroRuntimeBuilder[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961291313] [levelValue: 800] Built Payara Micro Runtime

H2 home ====== null
[2020-03-23T12:01:36.827+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961296827] [levelValue: 800] Boot Command set returned with result SUCCESS : PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: set AdminCommandnull
    configs.config.server-config.hazelcast-config-specific-configuration.lite=false


[2020-03-23T12:01:36.848+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961296848] [levelValue: 800] Boot Command set returned with result SUCCESS : PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: set AdminCommandnull
    hazelcast-runtime-configuration.host-aware-partitioning=true


[2020-03-23T12:01:36.856+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961296856] [levelValue: 800] Boot Command set returned with result SUCCESS : PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: set AdminCommandnull
    hazelcast-runtime-configuration.discovery-mode=multicast


[2020-03-23T12:01:37.298+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296867] [timeMillis: 1584961297298] [levelValue: 800] Data grid encryption is enabled

[2020-03-23T12:01:37.359+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94morg.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296867] [timeMillis: 1584961297359] [levelValue: 800] Registered fish.payara.ha.hazelcast.store.HazelcastBackingStoreFactoryProxy for persistence-type = hazelcast in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry

[2020-03-23T12:01:41.880+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296867] [timeMillis: 1584961301880] [levelValue: 800] Hazelcast Instance Bound to JNDI at payara/Hazelcast

[2020-03-23T12:01:41.881+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296867] [timeMillis: 1584961301881] [levelValue: 800] JSR107 Caching Provider Bound to JNDI at payara/CachingProvider

[2020-03-23T12:01:41.881+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296867] [timeMillis: 1584961301881] [levelValue: 800] JSR107 Default Cache Manager Bound to JNDI at payara/CacheManager

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.086+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.core[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296862] [timeMillis: 1584961302086] [levelValue: 800] Network Listener http-listener started in: 10ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.088+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [NCLS-CORE-00058] [[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.core[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296862] [timeMillis: 1584961302088] [levelValue: 800] Network listener https-listener on port 8443 disabled per domain.xml

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.089+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.core[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1584961296862] [timeMillis: 1584961302089] [levelValue: 800] Grizzly 2.4.3 started in: 4.967ms - bound to [http-listener:8080]

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.121+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.cluster.PayaraCluster[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=86 _ThreadName=Executor-Service-5] [timeMillis: 1584961302121] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Data Grid Status
Payara Data Grid State: DG Version: 35 DG Name: development DG Size: 1
Instances: {
 DataGrid: development Instance Group: MicroShoal Name: Zealous-Catfish Lite: false This: true UUID: 97c92cea-def5-42c7-9106-ea03bbc4d4f0 Address: /192.168.1.106:6900
}]]

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.122+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.core[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961302122] [levelValue: 800] Payara Micro  5.201 #badassmicrofish (512) startup time : Embedded (5.541ms), startup services(5.266ms), total(10.807ms)

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.210+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [NCLS-JMX-00006] [[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.jmx[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=93 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1584961302210] [levelValue: 800] JMXStartupService has disabled JMXConnector system

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.253+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961302253] [levelValue: 800] Hazelcast Instance Unbound from JNDI at payara/Hazelcast

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.253+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961302253] [levelValue: 800] JSR107 Caching Provider Unbound from JNDI at payara/CachingProvider

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.254+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961302254] [levelValue: 800] JSR107 Cache Manager Unbound from JNDI at payara/CacheManager

[2020-03-23T12:01:42.278+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961302278] [levelValue: 800] Shutdown Hazelcast

[2020-03-23T12:01:45.812+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961305812] [levelValue: 800] Hazelcast Instance Bound to JNDI at payara/Hazelcast

[2020-03-23T12:01:45.813+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961305813] [levelValue: 800] JSR107 Caching Provider Bound to JNDI at payara/CachingProvider

[2020-03-23T12:01:45.813+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961305813] [levelValue: 800] JSR107 Default Cache Manager Bound to JNDI at payara/CacheManager

[2020-03-23T12:01:45.817+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mfish.payara.nucleus.cluster.PayaraCluster[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=Executor-Service-3] [timeMillis: 1584961305817] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Data Grid Status
Payara Data Grid State: DG Version: 35 DG Name: development DG Size: 1
Instances: {
 DataGrid: development Instance Group: MicroShoal Name: Tame-Daggertooth Lite: false This: true UUID: 26b439e8-293d-43c6-958f-3fab3a614c86 Address: /192.168.1.106:6900
}]]

[2020-03-23T12:01:45.825+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mPayaraMicro[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961305825] [levelValue: 800] Deployed 0 archive(s)

[2020-03-23T12:01:45.909+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mPayaraMicro[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961305909] [levelValue: 800]
{
    "Instance Configuration": {
        "Host": "192.168.1.106",
        "Http Port(s)": "8080",
        "Https Port(s)": "",
        "Instance Name": "Tame-Daggertooth",
        "Instance Group": "MicroShoal",
        "Hazelcast Member UUID": "26b439e8-293d-43c6-958f-3fab3a614c86",
        "Deployed": [
        ]
    }
}

[2020-03-23T12:01:45.918+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mPayaraMicro[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961305918] [levelValue: 800]
Payara Micro URLs:



[2020-03-23T12:01:45.918+0100] [] [[1;92mINFORMAZIONI[0m] [] [[1;94mPayaraMicro[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1584961305918] [levelValue: 800] Payara Micro  5.201 #badassmicrofish (build 512) ready in 14.592 (ms)
```

Nevertheless, when I open the browser, the following message is displayed:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a bunch to who will help me!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was a problem with internet cache.